# How do I generate the Fibonacci sequence without using a list?

Tags: python, for-loop, fibonacci

I have been asked the following:

> Using a while-loop, write a program that generates a Fibonacci
>   sequence of integers. Your program should ask the user how many
>   Fibonacci sequence entries to generate and print this quantity of them
>   to the screen.

I don't know where to begin.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I wasn't aware that a list is required to generate the fibonacci sequence.  I always just used two variables in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

use a variable to hold last value and current value, print the current value, and then update the last value... don't want to write it for you :)

Comment: think i got it? #fib sequence 

n=int(input("Enter the number of sequences you want: "))
i=0 
first=0 
second=1 
next=1 
other="none" 
while i<n: 
    i=i+1 
    next=first+second
    first=second 
    second=next 
    print (next)

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about this problem a little bit before just giving out the answer:

The fibonacci sequence is of the form
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ...

So as you can see your next number is the sum of the previous two numbers so, based on its definition you can tell you need two variables to store the previous two numbers in and a variable to store the sum in. You also need to know when you need to terminate your loop (the number you get from the user).

Looks like someone has already posted it for you...never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Every fibonacci number is generated as the sum of the previous two fibonacci numbers. The first two fibonacci numbers are `0` and `1`.

Using the above as the definition, let's start designing your code:

```
function fibonnacci:
    n := ask user how many numbers to output  # hint: use raw_input() and int()
    if n is 1:
        output 0
    else if n is 2:
        output 0, 1
    else:
        output 0, 1
        lastNumber := 1
        twoNumbersAgo := 0
        count up from 3 to n:
            nextNumber := twoNumbersAgo + lastNumber
            output nextNumber
            twoNumbersAgo := lastNumber
            lastNumber = nextNumber
end function
```